# Mailcleaner new beta installation problems

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I have installed the mailcleaner beta 2017.04 and I have a few problems here :

1) I get a message via email every 5 minutes with this error :

```
"Invalid graph type: none at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/RRDTool/OO.pm line 1110."
```

2)  I do not receive any spam reports via email. I have no errors in the log files. Seems that the sending script is not working.

Is the tow problems related ?
Someone could help me here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we notice that too ! We forgot to relaunch a script after a needed modification (install of SHA module for perl). You can simply launch it manually to correct the problem:

```
/usr/mailcleaner/install/install_perl_libs.sh
```

Same problem than before, a perl module (RRDTool) is patched by this script and we didn't launch it again after adding the corresponding perl version. If you launched it for previous question this is adressed already. Else launch:

```
/usr/mailcleaner/install/install_perl_libs.sh
```

Comment: As per the "we", it sounds that there is some type of relationship between you (author of this answer), and the software this question is about. If that's indeed the case, what kind of relationship?